# Error PDO: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter

Tags: php, pdo

Éste es mi código:

```
$errors = array();
$data = array();

if ((empty($_POST['nombre']))||(ctype_space($_POST['nombre'])))
    $errors['nombre'] = 'Nombre (s)';

if ((empty($_POST['apellidoP']))||(ctype_space($_POST['apellidoP'])))
    $errors['apellidoP'] = 'Apellido Paterno';

if ((empty($_POST['apellidoM']))||(ctype_space($_POST['apellidoM'])))
    $errors['apellidoM'] = 'Apellido Materno';

if ((empty($_POST['direccion']))||(ctype_space($_POST['direccion'])))
    $errors['direccion'] = 'Dirección';

if ((empty($_POST['usuario']))||(ctype_space($_POST['usuario'])))
    $errors['usuario'] = 'Usuario';

if ((empty($_POST['contrasenia']))||(ctype_space($_POST['contrasenia'])))
    $errors['contrasenia'] = 'Contrase&ntilde;a';

if ((empty($_POST['rfc']))||(ctype_space($_POST['rfc'])))
    $errors['rfc'] = 'RFC';

if ((empty($_POST['telefono']))||(ctype_space($_POST['telefono'])))
    $errors['telefono'] = 'Teléfono';

if ((empty($_POST['email']))||(ctype_space($_POST['email'])))
    $errors['email'] = 'E-mail';

if ( !empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
    $data['message']  = 'Verifique los siguientes datos: ';
    $data['info'] = 'error';
}
else
{   $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidoP = $_POST['apellidoP'];
    $apellidoM = $_POST['apellidoM'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $contrasenia = $_POST['contrasenia'];
    $rfc = $_POST['rfc'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if ((empty($_POST['activo']))||(ctype_space($_POST['activo']))){
        $activo = '0';}
    else{
            $activo = $_POST['activo'];
        }       
    $acceso = $_POST['nivel'];

    $db->where('usuario',$usuario); 
    $db->where('id_usuario',$_SESSION['idusu'],'<>','AND'); 
    $campos = "COUNT(usuario) as total ";
    $resultado = $db->get("usuario",null,$campos);
    if($resultado){
        foreach ($resultado as $key) {
            $total=$key['total'];
        }
    }
    if ($total>0){  
        $errors['usuario'] = 'Usuario';
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
        $data['message'] = "Ya existe un usuario con este dato:"; 
        $data['info'] = 'error';
    }
    else{

        $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET 
                       nombre = :nombre,
                       app = :app,
                       apm = :apm,
                       direccion =:direccion,
                       usuario = :usuario,
                       contrasenia = :contrasenia,
                       rfc = :rfc,
                       celular = :telefono,
                       email = :mail,
                       estatus = :activo,
                       acceso = :nivel,
                       alta_usuario =:alta_usuario
                        WHERE id_usuario = :id_usuario";


        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);                                  
        $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':app', $apellidoP, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':apm', $apellidoM, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':direccion', $direccion, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':contrasenia', $contrasenia, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':rfc', $rfc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':celular', $telefono, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':estatus', $activo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':acceso', $nivel, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':alta_usuario', $alta_usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_usuario', $_SESSION['idusu'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $resultado = $stmt->execute();

        if($resultado>0)
        {
            $data['success'] = true;
            $data['message'] = "El usuario se ha modificado satisfactoriamente";  
            $data['id'] = $resultado;
        }
        else
        {
            $data['success'] = false;
            $data['message'] = 'Error en la modificaci&oacute;n del registro';
        }
    }
}   
break;
```

---

### MODULO DE USUARIOS
                    Ingrese la información correspondiente.

### MODIFICA USUARIO

```
                    </div>
                    <div class="body">
                        <form id="form_validation" method="post" action="ajaxusuarios.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <?php
                        $db->where('id_usuario',$_SESSION['usuario']);  
                        $campos = "usuario,contrasenia,acceso,estatus,nombre,app,apm,rfc,direccion,email,celular,alta_usuario";
                        $resultado = $db->get("usuario",null,$campos);//nombre de la tabla USUARIOS
                        if($resultado){
                            foreach ($resultado as $key) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="row clearfix">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <div class="form-line">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='nombre' value="<?php echo $key['nombre'];?>" required/>
                                        <label class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <div class="form-line">
                                        <input type="app" class="form-control" name='apellidoP' value="<?php echo $key['app'];?>" required>
                                        <label class="form-label">Apellido Paterno</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <div class="form-line">
                                        <input type="app" class="form-control" name='apellidoM' value="<?php echo $key['apm'];?>" required>
                                        <label class="form-label">Apellido Maternos</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-float">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="direccion" value="<?php echo $key['direccion'];?>" required/>
                                    <label class="form-label">Dirección</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="row clearfix">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <div class="form-line">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='usuario' value="<?php echo $key['usuario'];?>" required/>
                                        <label class="form-label">Usuario</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <div class="form-line">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name='contrasenia' value="<?php echo $key['contrasenia'];?>" required>
                                        <label class="form-label">Password</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <!--<div class="form-group form-float">-->
                                    <div class="demo-switch"><b>Activo</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <div class="switch">
                                            <label>No
                                            <?php if ($key['estatus']==1) {?>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="estatus" value="1" checked/>
                                            <?php } else {?>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="estatus" value="1" />
                                            <?php }?>   
                                            <span class="lever switch-col-<?php echo $_SESSION['color']; ?>"></span>Si</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <!--</div>-->
                            </div>
                         </div>
                        <div class="row clearfix">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <b>Número Telefonico</b>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="material-icons">phone</i>
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="form-line">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control mobile-phone-number" placeholder="(000) 000-00-00" name="telefono"  value="<?php echo $key['celular'];?>" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <b>Nivel de Acceso Administrador</b>
                                <div class="demo-radio-button">
                                    <?php if ($key['estatus']==1) {
                                        echo "<input name='nivel' type='radio' class='with-gap radio-col-".$_SESSION['color']."' id='radio_1' value='1' checked />";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<input name='nivel' type='radio' class='with-gap radio-col-".$_SESSION['color']."' id='radio_1' value='1' />";
                                    } ?>
                                    <label for="radio_1">Seleccionar</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <b>Nivel de Acceso Programador</b>
                                <div class="demo-radio-button">
                                    <?php if ($key['estatus']==2) {
                                        echo "<input name='nivel' type='radio' class='with-gap radio-col-".$_SESSION['color']."' id='radio_2' value='2' checked/>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<input name='nivel' type='radio' class='with-gap radio-col-".$_SESSION['color']."' id='radio_2' value='2' />";
                                    } ?>
                                    <label for="radio_2">Seleccionar</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row clearfix">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <b>RFC</b>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="form-line">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="RFC" name="rfc"  value="<?php echo $key['rfc'];?>" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <b>Nivel de Acceso Agende de Campo</b>
                                <div class="demo-radio-button">
                                    <?php if ($key['estatus']==3) {
                                        echo "<input name='nivel' type='radio' class='with-gap radio-col-".$_SESSION['color']."' id='radio_3' value='3' checked />";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<input name='nivel' type='radio' class='with-gap radio-col-".$_SESSION['color']."' id='radio_3' value='3' />";
                                    } 

                                    ?>
                                    <label for="radio_3">Seleccionar</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <b>Nivel de Acceso Agente de Oficina</b>
                                <div class="demo-radio-button">
                                    <?php if ($key['estatus']==4) {
                                        echo "<input name='nivel' type='radio' class='with-gap radio-col-".$_SESSION['color']."' id='radio_4' value='4' checked/>";
                                    } else {
                                        echo "<input name='nivel' type='radio' class='with-gap radio-col-".$_SESSION['color']."' id='radio_4' value='4' />";
                                    } 

                                    ?>
                                    <label for="radio_4">Seleccionar</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row clearfix">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <b>E-mail</b>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="material-icons">mail</i>
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="form-line">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control mail" placeholder="mail@example.com" name="email"  value="<?php echo $key['email'];?>" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                         <?php }}?>

                            <divl class="col-xs-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg bg-<?php echo $_SESSION['color']; ?> waves-effect" type="submit"><b>Modificar</b></button>
                            </div>
                        </form>                            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Éste es el mensaje de error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: parameter was not defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Agencia
>   Nuba/Nubawork/work/ajaxusuarios.php:216 Stack trace: #0
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/Agencia Nuba/Nubawork/work/ajaxusuarios.php(216):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Agencia
>   Nuba/Nubawork/work/ajaxusuarios.php on line 216

Comment: Ese es mi código completo, ¿podrías echarle un ojo? , porfa?

Comment: Hola @Rocío, para la próxima procura dejar el comentario en mi respuesta para que sea notificado, menos mal que me pasé (por casualidad) por esta pregunta. También puedes preceder mi nombre con un @ para que también sea notificado aunque no sea en una respuesta mía. ¿Echaste un vistazo a mi respuesta? ¿Ayudó algo? ¿Nada?

Comment: @OscarGarcia, perdón, soy nueva en el foro.
No, no me ayudó :/.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Voy a mirar, ¿podrías adjuntar también el HTML del formulario para no tener que desarrollarlo yo?

Comment: @OscarGarcia, claro

Comment: Parece que el error es el que yo decía, pero había otro campo más que modificar... voy a editar mi respuesta

Comment: Ahora debería funcionar. 13 variables del tipo `:variable` con sus 13 asignaciones con `bindParam`.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un error en la asignación de variables, has cambiado el nombre de varias y no coinciden, por lo que la consulta no puede ejecutarse sin ellas (de ahí el mensaje "Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined" o "número de parámetros inválido: parámetro no fue definido", aunque no indique el número de ellos):

```
app = :apellidoP,
apm = :apellidoM,
...
celular = :telefono,
email = :mail,
estatus = :activo,
acceso = :nivel,
```

Se deberían cambiar por:

```
app = :app,
apm = :apm,
...
celular = :celular,
email = :email,
estatus = :estatus,
acceso = :acceso,
```

Para que concuerde con:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':app', $apellidoP, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':apm', $apellidoM, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':celular', $telefono, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':estatus', $activo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':acceso', $nivel, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

El código quedaría:

```
    $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET 
                   nombre = :nombre,
                   app = :app,
                   apm = :apm,
                   direccion =:direccion,
                   usuario = :usuario,
                   contrasenia = :contrasenia,
                   rfc = :rfc,
                   celular = :celular,
                   email = :email,
                   estatus = :estatus,
                   acceso = :acceso,
                   alta_usuario =:alta_usuario
                    WHERE id_usuario = :id_usuario";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);                                  
    $stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':app', $apellidoP, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':apm', $apellidoM, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':direccion', $direccion, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':contrasenia', $contrasenia, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':rfc', $rfc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':celular', $telefono, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':estatus', $activo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':acceso', $nivel, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':alta_usuario', $alta_usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id_usuario', $_SESSION['idusu'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $resultado = $stmt->execute();
```

Por lo demás no pasa nada si la variable que asignas se llama `$apellidoP` en vez de `$app`.

Lo importante que debes recordar es que por cada variable que crees de la forma `:variable` debes asignarle un valor con `bindParam(':variable', $laVariableQueQueramos, PDO::...)`.

Comment: Hola Oscar, ese código tambíén fallará. Si en la cadena SQL tienes los **valores** como: `celular=:telefono... email=:mail... estatus=:activo... acceso=:nivel...` en el **binding** los **valores** de columnas deben estar escritos igual, ese es el motivo del error _parameter was not defined_ Esto por ejemplo está mal: `$stmt->bindParam(':celular', $telefono, PDO::PARAM_STR);`, debería ser: `$stmt->bindParam(':telefono', $telefono, PDO::PARAM_STR);` y así los otros que he señalado. Porque en PDO **ese valor no representa el nombre de la columna, sino el valor que quieres pasarle**.

Comment: Lo estaba viendo

Comment: @OscarGarcia,   gracias por tomarte el tiempo, ahora ya no me genera ningún error.

Comment: @A.Cedano, gracias!!

Comment: De nada @Rocío Esa confusión es muy frecuente cuando uno empieza con PDO. **En el binding siempre van los valores con los dos puntos (:) como están escritos en la consulta SQL.** O sea los de la derecha. Para evitar confusión es mejor siempre escribirlos igual. Si escribes esto: `$correo=yo@yo.com; UPDATE usuario SET nombre = :nombre, ...  email = :mail...`, te puedes confundir al hacer el binding. Por eso mejor darle el mismo nombre en todas partes: `$email=yo@yo.com; UPDATE usuario SET nombre = :nombre, ...  email = :email...` ya cuando hagas el bind sabrás que se llama siempre `email`. :)

Comment: Puedes votar su comentario como he hecho yo pulsando en el símbolo . Gracias también​ @A.Cedano, me pillaste en otro editor en el que llegué a la conclusión de que faltaban más variables por asignar. Yo he preferido siempre poner el mismo nombre que el campo o alias a las variables para su asignación, así (al menos para mí) la depuración de algún posible error es más intuitivo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia De nada. Lo importante es que se ha resuelto. Comentar también que con PDO podemos pasar arreglos enteros de campos y de valores. Es una de las cosas por las que me encanta PDO con respecto a MySQLi, de hecho, [estoy desarrollando una clase de conexión](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO) en la que a través de una sola llamada pasas todos los parámetros. Ejemplo: `$datos=$mipdo->query(
                   "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id_provincia = :idprovincia AND id_estado = :idestado",
                   array("id_provincia"=>"1","id_estado"=>"5")
                  );`

Comment: Esa clase ahorra mucho código en la mayoría de casos, es cierto. Le he hecho fork, la veré más tarde y recibirás un pull request si veo algo interesante que incluir :). También soy de PDO más que de mysqli (de hecho, pasé directamente de mysql a pdo/mysql sin pasar por mysqli).

Comment: Bueno la clase no está completa, le faltan algunos métodos. Ahora funciona para lo esencial. @Rocío viendo tu reputación considero que acabas de llegar a este sitio. Considerando que la respuesta de Oscar debidamente editada ha resuelto este error, puedes marcarla como solucionado, activando el signo de cotejo que aparece a la izquierda de la respuesta. Y puedes también darle un voto a favor si no lo has hecho, pulsando en la flecha gris que apunta hacia arriba, también a la izquierda.